# Triple boot on MacBook Pro probelm

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, uefi, macbook

I first installed Windows 10 using BootCamp, everything was working fine. Then after I installed Ubuntu 14.04, everytime I try to boot into Windows using the Option key at the start-up I get this message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

This piece of message is shown twice and then it redirects me to the Ubuntu start-up interface(with the Ubuntu, Advanced Options and so on). I have one option in this menu: "**efi/boot/bkpbootx64.efi**" which sends me to a blue screen on Windows showing me the following message in a text box: "

> It looks like you started an upgrade and booted from installation
>   media. If you want to continue with the upgrade, remove the media from
>   your PC and click Yes. If you want to perform a clean installation
>   instead, click No.

" If I press either **No** or **Esc** it sends me to a Windows installation window, but I don'twant  to install it again since I have very important data on my already installed one. I tried to use Boot-Repair but it didn't change anything. How can I access Windows again without losing my data?